# Best Async Design for Data Load via Network calls, Kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I have to do several network calls (using Retrofit) in an async manner.
Some of them are connected, as in if I get back response from call 2 that fulfills my condition, then i can skip the result from 3 and 4 and proceed, otherwise I have to use response from 3 and 4 and proceed.

Say R1, R2, R3, R4 are 4 requests that I run in an async way to populate my response object. If R2 gives back `true` then I have to avoid a field populated by R3 and R4 and replace it with a predefined value. If R2 is `false` then field should be derived from response of R3 and R4.

How can I use coroutine concepts to achieve this? If R2 is `true` and I don't avoid R3 and R4, and if R3 and R4 finish afterwards, I might end up updating the value as per R3 and R4, or wait for it to finish and then determine the value.

Answer (score 2):

With coroutines this is pretty easy. Make all your requests suspendable and then use the code similar to the following:

```kotlin
val r1 = async { sendR1() }
val r2 = async { sendR2() }
val r3 = async { sendR3() }
val r4 = async { sendR4() }

if (r2.await()) {
    // use predefined
} else {
    // use r3.await() and r4.await()
}
```

Comment: And you might want to call `r3.cancel()` and `r4.cancel()` inside the `if` block to avoid wasting bandwidth in case they take a while longer.

Comment: As this will be a regular function from where my code should run all these async calls and after it get response (await ) completes then only it sends back response from service. What scope should be used for this ? Should i call all these async scope calls inside a runBlocking ? Or a GlobalScope.async ? How to determine that, @Tenfour04 can you please explain

Comment: You could wrap the function contents in `runBlocking` for this purpose, although in an app that's already using coroutines, it's more natural to use a suspend function so the function can easily be used from other coroutines without worrying about blocking. There are certain cases where you may actually want or need a blocking function though.